# Action Routing: Application gets confused between the GET and POST methods

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core-mvc

**Context:**

The view constructed with the GET method takes at this moment two parameters: `id` and `date`. In this view there is a form which sends information back to the Controller thru the POST method using the parameter `id`

***GET Method***

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAdmin(int? id, [ModelBinder(typeof(PModelBinder))]DateTime? date)
    {
       {...}
    }
```

***POST Method***

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DetailsAdmin")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("HechosLiquidadors/DetailsAdmin/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAdmin(int? id)
    {
       {...}
    }
```

**The problem:**

When the form inside the View sends the information to the Controller, it goes to the GET Action instead of the POST action.

***The form:***

```
<form id="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",Model[i].HechosID))" 
asp-action="DetailsAdmin" method="post" asp-route-id="@Model[i].HechosID" ></form>
```

I've tried using a Custom Routing to the POST Action method but no luck. How can I correct this so the form points to the POST Action correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In both action methods all parameters as optional. therefore Mvc cannot select "Best candidate" method for executing.
change first action as below and check id not 0:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DetailsAdmin(int id = 0, [ModelBinder(typeof(PModelBinder))]DateTime? date)
{
    if (id != 0)
    {

    }
    {...}
}
```